# What is the best way to attach to a cron program without TTY

Tags: cron, tmux, gnu-screen, tty

My ubuntu VM does not run `cron` jobs with a TTY (not even when I log in and run the command from the user's env).

Because of this, cron can't run `tmux` or `screen`, preventing programs (specifically `rtorrent` in this case) to be run in the background in a simple and attachable way.

What is the best approach to running a program like `rtorrent` on boot while making it easy to attach, detach, and kill the process from any terminal?

I assume just running the equivalent of `rtorrent &` should do it, but this is not as convenient as screen/tmux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use the `-d` option with `tmux new`, it won't attach to or require a tty.  From `man tmux`:

> ```
> new-session [-AdDEP] [-c start-directory] [-F format] [-n window-name]
>             [-s session-name] [-t group-name] [-x width] [-y height]
>             [shell-command]
>             (alias: new)
> ```
>
> Create a new session with name session-name.
>
> The new session is attached to the current terminal unless `-d` is
>   given. [...]

For example:

```
tmux new -d -s rtorrent rtorrent
```

That creates a new `tmux` session called "rtorrent" and runs `rtorrent` inside it.

You will probably need to configure `~/.tmux.conf`, and run a script to start `rtorrent` (rather just the bare `rtorrent` command) in order to setup the run environment correctly.

The user who owns the cron job can attach to the session at any time with:

```
tmux attach -t rtorrent
```

The equivalent for Screen is

```
screen -d -m -S rtorrent rtorrent
```

from the cron job and `screen -S rtorrent -rd` to attach later.

Comment: Thank you. Is `rc.local` better than `init.d`? i.e. should the rtorrent/tmux session be a `service`? I suppose it depends on whether or not `init.d` services have access to `tty`

Comment: you could write an init.d script too if you want.  a systemd unit file is another alternative.  either would make it easier to stop/start the rtorrent-in-tmux service on demand.

Comment: BTW, The `-d` option to `tmux new` is what prevents it from attaching to (and thus requiring) a tty.  From `man tmux` (search for "new-session"): `The new session is attached to the current terminal unless -d is given.`.  There's no reason why this couldn't be run from `cron` - but IMO cron is the wrong way to start something like rtorrent so i gave an answer that provided an alternative (imo better) method.

Comment: Thank you for the hint about detached mode! I have it working now.

I tried using rc.local but there were some difficulties: the `-u` option is not recognized for the `su` command, additionally, it simply wasn't working and I didn't have time to debug.

`cron` it shall be for the time being. Thanks.

I marked your answer as correct, but you may want to add the `-d` hint to the top of your answer for others.

Comment: i'm too used to the sudo command, which does have a `-u` option.  never mind, i got rid of the rc.local and su stuff.  not necessary to answer the question.